# Rails split by full regex match

Tags: ruby, regex

How to split by full **regex** match? If **regex** contains groups, every full match will be an array of all groups. But how to get just an array of full matches, without them being divided further into groups?

Example:

```
"foo-14".scan(/(foo|bar)-([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/)
```

returns:

```
[["foo", "14"]]
```

but I want:

```
["foo-14"]
```

Split works similarly.

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and results along with what you've tried so far and what works and/or doesn't work.

Comment: Use `"foo-14".scan(/(?:foo|bar)-[0-9a-zA-Z]+/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use non-capturing groups in your regex:

```
"foo-14".scan(/(?:foo|bar)-[0-9a-zA-Z]+/)
#=> ["foo-14"]
```

Comment: Note that `?:` must be present in every group, hence for my exact example: `"foo-14".scan(/(?:foo|bar)-(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/)`

Comment: @user2340939 It should be present in every group, but `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` doesn't need to be grouped at all, unlike `foo|bar`, which needs grouping for the _or_ (`|`) to work.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to emphasize it.

Comment: @user2340939 Ohh, i misread your comment. Yes, for your exact example both will need to be non-capturing groups.

Comment: or `[[:alnum:]]` (POSIX) or `\p{Alnum}` (`\p{Alnum}` construct) in place of `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.